# Onclick button to switch between iframe maps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I want to display different 3 maps in the same page by clicking on 3 different buttons.
I used this code but I don't know how to swich betwen the maps by clicking on the buttons. I think I need a javascript functions but I dont know how to do it. I am new in web programming

[The 3 buttons I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEMgo.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <title>MAps</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class ="navButton">
            <button class="btn bruce">Buton1 </button>
            <button class="btn info">Button2</button>
            <button class="btn warning">Buton3</button>
          </div>
          
          <iframe width="1700" height="1200" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
              marginwidth="0" src="https://link to map1></iframe>
          <iframe width="1700" height="1200" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
                 marginwidth="0" src="https://link to map2></iframe>
          <iframe width="1700" height="1200" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
                 marginwidth="0" src="https://link to map3></iframe>
         </script>
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be careful about cross-domain iframes, and now to get to the point.

you can use a variable to see which iframe you want to show.

```
let a = 0;
```

Now, you can use the jQuery `$(obj).hide()` or `.show()` functions to switch between the three.

```
// func() runs when button is clicked (<button onclick="func()">text</button> in the HTML)
let a = 0;
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_iframe).hide()
function func() {
if(a === 0) {
$(first_iframe).show()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_frame).hide()
a++
} else if (a === 1) {
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).show()
$(third_frame).hide()
a++
} else if (a === 2) {
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_frame).show()
a = 0
}
}
```

This method only uses 1 button.
If you want to use three buttons,

```
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_iframe).hide()

function button1() {
$(first_iframe).show()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_frame).hide()
}

function button2() {
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).show()
$(third_frame).hide()
}

function button3() {
$(first_iframe).hide()
$(second_iframe).hide()
$(third_frame).show()
}
//add onclick events to the three buttons to their respective functions (in the html)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hermanboxcar. it works. I have to add more buttons now.   I appreciate your help!

Comment: Marking answers correct can help future users distinguish right and wrong answers. To mark an answer correct, click the check mark to the left of the answer.